# Scheduled task assistance please

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks

I am attempting to create a schedule task that (using the scheduled task wrapper) fires every 3 hours. I got the task installed for every day, but can't even after going through the documentation, get it to run every few hours. also not too sure about the LogonType. can anyone let me know where I am going wrong ?

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (TaskService ts = new TaskService())
        {
            var androback = ts.GetTask("Andro_Inc_Backup");
            bool taskExists = androback != null;
            if (taskExists)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Andromeda incremental backup task already installed");
            }
            else
            {
                TaskDefinition td = ts.NewTask();
                td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Incremental Backup";
                td.Principal.LogonType = TaskLogonType.ServiceAccount;
                td.Triggers.Add(new DailyTrigger { DaysInterval = 1 });
                td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("C:\\Rameses\\Program\\Inc_Cloud_Backup.exe", null));
                const string taskname = "Inc_Backup";
                ts.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition(taskname, td);
                MessageBox.Show("Incremental Backup Task Installed");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you are looking for the **dailyTrigger.Repetition.Interval** property.

```
DateTime datetime = DateTime.Today;
DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime(datetime.Year, datetime.Month, datetime.Day, 0, 0, 0);
DailyTrigger dailyTrigger = new DailyTrigger { StartBoundary = startDateTime, Enabled = true, DaysInterval = 1 };
dailyTrigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(23);
dailyTrigger.Repetition.Interval = TimeSpan.FromHours(3);
td.Triggers.Add(dailyTrigger);
```

You can use the weekly trigger sample on [codeplex](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/documentation) as a reference which adds a trigger that, starting tomorrow, will fire every other week on Monday and Saturday and repeat every 10 minutes for the following 11 hours

Additional examples are [here](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Examples&referringTitle=Documentation).